# Is there a way to make a user-defined Python function act like a built-in statement?

Tags: python

Is it possible to make a user-defined Python function act like a statement? In other words, I'd like to be able to say:

```
myfunc
```

rather than:

```
myfunc()
```

and have it get called anyway -- the way that, say, `print` would.

I can already hear you all composing responses about how this is a horrible thing to do and I'm stupid for asking it and why do I want to do this and I really should do something else instead, but please take my word that it's something I need to do to debug a problem I'm having and it's not going to be checked in or used for, like, an air traffic control system.

Comment: I'm curious, what situation could possibly require you to do that?

Comment: Why don't you show us, what you have to debug, and we'll show you how to debug without creating statements.

Comment: Python only has 20 or so statements (like print) are you trying to replace one of those 20 statements as part of debugging?  If so, which one.  What specific problem do you have?

Comment: I'm also very curious about this.  I don't think statements like that are an abomination or anything; I just can't think of any situation where myfunc() wouldn't do exactly the same thing.

Comment: can you fix the question. All user-defined functions behave like built-in functions. You appear to want a function to behave like a statement.

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not possible.

As you can see from the [Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/3.0/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements), there is no room left for extensions of the list of simple statements in the specification.

Moreover, `print` as a statement no longer exists in Python 3.0 and is replaced by the `print()` builtin function.

Answer (score 3):

If what you're looking for is to add a new statement (like `print`) to Python's language, then this would not be easy. You'd probably have to modify lexer, parser and then recompile Python's C sources. A lot of work to do for a questionable convenience.

Answer (score 3):

I would not implement this, but if I was implementing this, I would give code with myfunc a special extension, write an import hook to parse the file, add the parenthesis to make it valid Python, and feed that into the interpreter.

Comment: Which means you'd make a preprocessor. Nice idea +1. He won't be able to use it interactively during debugging though, if that's what the requirements are. Well you could hook all compile()/exec() etc. too maybe...

Answer (score 2):

Not if you want to pass in arguments. You could do something build an object that ABUSES the `__str__` method, but it is highly not recommended. You can also use other operators like overload the `<<` operator like `cout` does in C++.

Comment: @Mike, look at creating an object and overriding the __lshift__ method. This is the method that corrosponds to the << operator. It takes in one argument which is the element being "shifted" into it.

@DzinX, no it would work anywhere.

Comment: How about abusing the __str__ method? Would that only work with "print myfunc" as opposed to just "myfunc" on its own?

Comment: You can override __repr__ and it will work in the interactive interpreter.  Doesn't work in general, though -- at least, not with my testing (python 2.5.1).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x print is not a function it is a statement just as if, while and def are statements.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in a planned way, or without a lot of work.

If you are bold and adventurous, read this wikipedia article about meta circular evaluation. Python has pretty good inspection and reflection on its own compiler/evaluater objects, you may be able to cobble something together along these lines.

> """Meta-circular implementations are suited to extending the language
>   they are written in. They are also useful for writing tools that are
>   tightly integrated with the programming language, such as
>   sophisticated debuggers. A language designed with a meta-circular
>   implementation in mind is often more suited for building languages in
>   general, even ones completely different from the host language."""

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-circular_evaluator

I believe pypy is doing something similarily, you might want to look into it.

- http://pypy.org

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't going to cover your problem, but I'll mention it anyway. If `myfunc` is part of a module, and you are using it like this:

```
from mymodule import myfunc
myfunc # I want this to turn into a function call
```

Then you could instead do this:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.myfunc # I want this to turn into a function call
```

You could then remove `myfunc` from `mymodule` and overload the module so it calls a particular function each time the `myfunc` member is requested.