# how to make my user defined function be a builtin function?

Tags: python

Can i make my user defined function to be a builtin function?
If i can make user defined function to be a builtin function ,i can directly call it  in the python console,it is more convenient  than `import`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a user-defined Python function act like a built-in statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489524/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-user-defined-python-function-act-like-a-built-in-statem)

Comment: The OP dosent state he wants the functions to behave like statements anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could run your python console with the `-i` switch and import your library, or edit the [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) to load your model each time the interpreter starts. These are the standard ways I know of to avoid importing explicitly.